# Compare value of attribute with child value in same node in XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

So, here is an example of the XML

```
<Grid>
  <GridRow ItemValue="10" ItemType="A">
    <YS_P_Name>L2</YS_P_Name>
    <YS_P_BK>10</YS_P_BK>
  </GridRow>
  <GridRow ItemValue="10" ItemType="A">
    <YS_P_Name>L3</YS_P_Name>
    <YS_P_BK>20</YS_P_BK>
  </GridRow>
  <GridRow ItemValue="30" ItemType="B">
    <YS_P_Name>L1</YS_P_Name>
    <YS_P_BK>40</YS_P_BK>
  </GridRow>
</Grid>
```

I need to find all children of **Grid** where the **ItemValue** value is **NOT** the same as **YS_P_BK**, with **ItemType** A. I tried loops, `following::` , `child::` all not working ... so, any suggestions?

Example: `/Grid/*[@ItemType='A' and @ItemValue != self::YS_P_BK::text()]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
/Grid/*[@ItemType="A" and @ItemValue != YS_P_BK]
```

will select all children of `Grid` with `ItemType` attribute value of `"A"` and a `ItemValue` attribute value not equal to the string value of its `YS_P_BK` child element.